# Protection against Keyloggers?

Tags: keyloggers

I was wondering, If I got infected with a Keylogger and I start my On-Screen Keyboard(from OS) and type things, will the symbols will be recorded (considering no Screenshots Keyloggers)? Since Keyloggers act on keystrokes I think this may work against Keylogger, correct me If I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are infected with a keylogger, it is a software keylogger and a software keylogger does not monitor the keyboard, it monitors the events that the OS fires off when a key is pressed.  These events are fired regardless of what type of input you use.  If a letter is generated as input, then it had to go to the OS and request the key be processed and the software keylogger will have seen it.

A hardware key logger is a physical device that is installed in-between the keyboard and computer and doesn't have to infect the computer since it is capturing the signals from the keyboard itself, but these are very rare since they have to be applied physically to the computer.

Comment: Oh yea, so any kind of input that request 'key' on OS will be recorded by the software keylogger..... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrect.

According to this wikipedia page [Keystroke_logging#On-screen_keyboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging#On-screen_keyboards) your keystrokes would be captured. This of course assumes its a software logger and not a hardware logger that sits between your keyboard and computer.  Hardware loggers may not be listening for keyboard events so you MAY be safe.

Comment: I will search if Hardware keyloggers save my strokes on the virtual keyboard... thanks for answer

Comment: An hardware keylogger can't capture the on-screen keyboard inputs, only the external keyboard itself.

But software keyloggers will indeed capture them, (at least a decent one...) you'd have no way of safe-typing, better install an AV? or firewall.

Comment: @SomeNickName of course I would install a AV and/or firewall, but im just being hypothetical to know if keylogger can do what I've said. Ty for suggestion

Comment: @Stephenloky and with a firewall (a decente one) you'd be 100% safe from 99% keyloggers.

Comment: @SomeNickName good to know ... thanks for the advices